# MySQL - Bit insert values not being inserted

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to move a local database onto an online one by copying the SQL content. Everything seems to work without any errors, but the tables that contain bit values are not working properly.

EDIT: So the inserts ARE actually working, the bits just aren't showing up in PhpMyAdmin for some reason in the main table view. However, none of the bit values are being picked up by my PHP code properly like they do locally... weird.

Is there some kind of setting that could be causing this to happen?

Here's one table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `distribution_partners` (
  `exchangeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `distr_health_plans` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `distr_supplemental_health_providers` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `distr_benefits_broker_agents` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `distr_benefit_consultants` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `distr_third_party_administrators` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `distr_direct_to_employers` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `distr_enable_public_exchanges` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `distr_association_industry_groups` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `distr_distribution_partners_other` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `distr_specify` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`exchangeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `distribution_partners` (`exchangeID`, `distr_health_plans`, `distr_supplemental_health_providers`, `distr_benefits_broker_agents`, `distr_benefit_consultants`, `distr_third_party_administrators`, `distr_direct_to_employers`, `distr_enable_public_exchanges`, `distr_association_industry_groups`, `distr_distribution_partners_other`, `distr_specify`) VALUES
(118, b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'0', ''),
(119, b'0', b'0', b'1', b'1', b'0', b'1', b'0', b'1', b'0', ''),
(120, b'1', b'0', b'1', b'1', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', ''),
(127, b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'0', ''),
(128, b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'1', b'1', b'0', b'0', b'0', '');
```

The create and insert both do not return any errors, but none of the bits are inserted.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bd5c/1

Comment: What version of PHPMyAdmin are you using? There was a bug reported for display of BIT data in version 3.5.2.2, and it's ok at least in version 4.0.9 (not yet released) http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3678/